# Passing data from child (I think?) of one Tab Bar View Controller to Collection View of another TabBarVC? (Programmatically)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitabbarcontroller

I'm building a tab bar controller based application programmatically. I'm trying to figure out that how to send data from what I take to be the child of one tab bar view controller (an additional presented VC on top of viewControllers[1]), to a collection view of another one of the tab bar VCs  at viewControllers[0]). I've read a bunch of entries here but none seem to be working for me or I'm not understanding them.

Essentially, within the VC in viewControllers[1], I've implemented a custom, full screen camera by implementing this code within the main TabVC.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
     if viewControllers?.firstIndex(of: viewController) == 1 {
         present(cameraVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
return true 
}
```

Then within that VC, I'm capturing the image and stacking a new editVC on top of that using present(editVC) to show the photo captured as well as some edit tools.  I say "stacking" even though I don't know if these actually become a part of a hierarchy when presented like this?  Could use some clarity on that. From that editingVC, I'm implementing the edits and saving the files to the documentsDirectory.  All that works fine and the image successfully saves.  But where I'm stuck is getting the path's address for the photo I've saved back to my collection view VC at viewControllers[0] so that I can populate its cells with the photo(s).

I've tried creating a delegate but I realized I can't set viewControllers[0] as a delegate for the (1st or maybe 2nd?) child of viewControllers[1]. (I'm unclear whether the code above essentially makes the cameraVC a child in an of itself of viewControllers[1].) Or can I/is it recommended?

Then I tried creating a state class containing an array of URLs (for the paths of the saved files) that both editVC could write to, and the viewControllers[0] collection view could read from. But I can't seem to get the editVC to update that array.  I suspect I am inadvertently creating multiple instances of that "state". class from each of my different VCs?

I have so much code I'm not certain what to post but hopefully this is relevant:

In the state class:

```
class StatePaths {
  var urls = [URL]()
}
```

**In the editVC**

```
//  declaration at the beginning of the class

    var statePaths: StatePaths?

// In the save func:

 let imageName = UUID().uuidString
        let imagePath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(imageName)

        if let jpegData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) {
            try? jpegData.write(to: imagePath)
            self.statePaths.urls.append(imagePath)
            self.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
```

**In the collection view of viewControllers[0]**

```
var statePaths = StatePaths()

// In the cellForItem func:

let path = statePaths[indexPath.item]
if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path.path) {
            cell.imageView.image = image
}
```

I also implemented some print statements that show the images are being saved, but that they are not populating the statePaths class.  I also implemented collectionView.reloadData() on ViewWillAppear of my collection VC.

Any help whether on these approaches or any others would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suspect I am inadvertently creating multiple instances of that
>   "state". class from each of my different VCs?

Yes, "statePaths" are multiple instances and no need to use it. You need to fetch the saved images at your viewControllers[0].

Also, the more clear way is to decouple this code to a separate model or service.
For example:

```
struct ImageStorage {

    static var documentsDirectory: String {
        return NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
    }

    static var imagesDirectory: String {
        let imagesDirectory = documentsDirectory + "/images/"
        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: imagesDirectory) {
            try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: imagesDirectory, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        }
        return imagesDirectory
    }

    static var images: [UIImage] {
        guard let paths = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: imagesDirectory) else {
            return []
        }
        let images = paths.compactMap { UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagesDirectory + $0) }
        return images
    }

    static func save(_ image: UIImage) {
        let imageName = UUID().uuidString
        let imagePath = imagesDirectory + imageName
        let imageUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: imagePath)

        guard let jpegData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) else {
            return
        }
        try? jpegData.write(to: imageUrl)
    }
}
```

Then use it in viewController:

```
ImageStorage.save(image)
ImageStorage.images
```

Upd. To question about passing data: It depends.

In some cases you can pass data to viewController by using delegates, tabBarViewController stack, NotificationCenter etc.

But in other cases easier to use singleton for temporarily storing the data.
As I can see the link between viewControllers is not so obvious in your case. So the singleton is preferred.

As example:

```
class StatePaths {    
    static let shared = StatePaths()    
    private init() {}

    var urls = [URL]()
}

StatePaths.shared.urls = urls
let urls = StatePaths.shared.urls
```

Comment: Thanks for this, and I see how this is a superior way to save the images and will implement a version of it.  But I'm still looking for how to pass data between the view controllers I mentioned, as there are other types of data--for example, String Optionals--I'd like to pass back to the collection view at viewControllers[0].

Comment: This works!  The combination of these solutions is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!!